# How to access Google Contacts 'relations' via Apps Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-contacts-api

I am trying to access the [Relations class](https://developers.google.com/gdata/jsdoc/2.0/google/gdata/contacts/Relation) via Google Apps Scripts. It seems that Contact class in Apps Scripts doesn't have that functionality and I can't access it via [CustomField class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/custom-field) either.

I wonder if there is a work around.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can call the contacts API as though it were an [external API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external), which would allow you to leverage it's entire functionality.